# How to find E[XY] when not independents, X is discrete, and Y binomial

Tags: probability

I have the marginal and joint probabilities (In the form of a probability table).

$X$ can take the values as $\{2, 6, 12\}$ and $Y$ is binomial taking $\{0, 1\}$. I want to calculate $E[XY]$ to later calc $COV[X,Y]$ and correlation.

Edit: I tried applying the formula $E[XY]=\sum\limits_{x \in X}\sum\limits_{y \in Y}x \, y \, P(X=x,Y=y)$ but I don't think is correct because of the binomial $Y$.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Thank you! I'll add what I was trying to do

Comment: That formula is correct. It does not matter that $Y$ is binomial.

Comment: Thank you @MikeEarnest ! May I bother you if I ask you to recommend me a book to learn probability? Particularly one which explains statistical moments easy and detailed? I'm interested (in need because of classes) in multivariate normal (though I assume I don't have a strong foundation in single variable distributions either) conditional probabilities and all the basics. Multiple books would also be okay, and actually really welcomed! Again thank you so much and sorry if this is offtopic

Comment: As stated in the description $X$ and $Y$ appear to be independent.  There is no description of any relation.

Comment: You could try Sheldon Ross’s An First Course in Probability. That’s the most recent book I used for my undergrad students. Kind of more theoretical than hands on though